# Getting every combination in a data frame when data already exist in some rows (R)

Tags: r, reshape2

I recently just used dcast (in the reshape2 package) to condense my data frame from long format to wide (since I needed counts). Now, I need to fill in the combination that do NOT exist with a 0. I imagine I could do something with expand.grid in the base package but I'm not sure how (?) since I don't just want every combo but I also already have some counts. An example of what I have:

```
AgeGroup Sex Month Count 
10       F   2     4
10       F   6     1
11       M   6     2
```

And what I would like:

```
AgeGroup Sex Month Count
10       F   2     4
10       F   3     0
10       F   4     0 
10       F   5     0
10       F   6     1
```

Edit in response to Anada's comment:

Minimum reproducible data/code:

```
library(reshape2)

Sex <- c('M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M')
County <- c(41, 65, 35, 49, 41)
AgeGroup <- c(11, 10, 18, 11, 11)
Month <- c(1, 1, 2, 4, 1)
Count <- rep(1, 5)
DF <- cbind.data.frame(Sex, County, AgeGroup, Month, Count)

DF <-dcast(DF, County+Sex+Month+AgeGroup~Count, 
           value.var="Count", length)

names(DF)[names(DF)=='1'] <- 'Count'
```

Note that in this example two observations are identical on purpose to demonstrate how I want to collapse things. I also don't know why but dcast renames the Count column so I have to change the name at the end.

Comment: Use `expand.grid` to generate all combinations, and then use `merge`

Comment: Perhaps a better option is to step back in your code. Using `dcast` on proper `factors` that have all the `levels` you want should allow you to keep everything you're interested in. Can you post some sample original data and the code you used to get to your first table above?

Comment: Thanks Ananda - I've included an example now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are asking for correctly, I believe you can do this with another of Hadley Wickham's packages: `plyr`

using the `ddply` function and specifying `.drop = F`

try:

```
ddply(df, .(AgeGroup, Sex, Month),length, .drop = F)
```

Comment: This code doesn't quite work for me but I'll look into ddply, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with base R. If `df` is your dataframe, you can try:

```
    res<-expand.grid(lapply(df[,1:3],unique))
    res$Count<-0
    res$Count[match(do.call(paste,df[,1:3]),do.call(paste,res[,1:3]))]<-df$Count
```

You evaluate the unique values for each column and build a data.frame from them through `expand.grid`. Next, you set each `Count` to zero and update the ones present in the original data.frame matching the values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (fast) `data.table` solution (assuming your data called `df`)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), AgeGroup, Sex, Month) # Sorting/keying your data set for future merge
combs <- df[, CJ(unique(AgeGroup), unique(Sex), seq_len(max(Month)))] # CJ is data.tables equivalent expand.grid, but more efficient 
final <- df[combs] # Merging
final[is.na(Count), Count := 0] # Setting all missing combinations to zero
final
#     AgeGroup Sex Month Count
#  1:       10   F     1     0
#  2:       10   F     2     4
#  3:       10   F     3     0
#  4:       10   F     4     0
#  5:       10   F     5     0
#  6:       10   F     6     1
#  7:       10   M     1     0
#  8:       10   M     2     0
#  9:       10   M     3     0
# 10:       10   M     4     0
# 11:       10   M     5     0
# 12:       10   M     6     0
# 13:       11   F     1     0
# 14:       11   F     2     0
# 15:       11   F     3     0
# 16:       11   F     4     0
# 17:       11   F     5     0
# 18:       11   F     6     0
# 19:       11   M     1     0
# 20:       11   M     2     0
# 21:       11   M     3     0
# 22:       11   M     4     0
# 23:       11   M     5     0
# 24:       11   M     6     2
```